# Godot TileMap.set_cell() : In which order are the transformations done? (flip then transpose or the opposite?)

Tags: godot, procedural-generation

I'm trying to procedurally generate a 2d terrain in Godot with a tilemap. I'm using a tileset without tile rotated, but want to be able to flip/transpose/rotate my tiles when I place them, and be able to retrieve the transformation applied to an already placed tile.
The function TileMap.set_cell() offers 3 paramters (flip_x, flip_y and transpose) to be able to orient my tiles as I please, and other functions such as TileMap.is_cell_transposed and TileMap.is_cell_x_flipped allows me to retrieve the applied transformations. Up to here, it seems everything is fine...

But the problem is how do I know in which order the transformations are applied? Is it transpose -> flip_x? Or flip_x -> transpose? The result is not always the same...

Am I missing something? I can't find the answer anywhere, but there might be a workaround or something?

Thanks for your help :)

Léo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved my issue. Writing the question made me think...

I tried all 8 combinations (flip x, flip y and transpose): Here is the results
[image: 8 tranformation of a square sprite]

So it seems that the transposition is done first, then the flips. Now I "just" need to adapt my code...